# Nest 6.2.0 Self Referencing Loop

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am using Nest v6.2.0 to connect to elastic search.

When I am trying to add a document of type A to an index I get a Self Referencing loop error because the object of type A has a property of type B and type B has a property of type A. Both objects of type A & B are database objects.

I can set the  ReferenceLoopHandling setting to  ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore on a JsonParser and it can parse the object fine, but I can't seem to send that json string to elastic search. So how can I set the same setting on the Json Parser used by Nest? SO that I can send the object to elastic search and Nest can correctly parse the object without the self referencing loop error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use different, simpler POCOs to model the documents that you're sending to Elasticsearch, to avoid potentially large object graphs through self-referencing loops.

You can reference [`Nest.JsonNetSerializer` nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NEST.JsonNetSerializer/) and [hook up Json.NET as the serializer to use with NEST](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/custom-serialization.html#_jsonnetserializer), configuring the ReferenceLoopHandling property

```
var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));

var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool, (builtInSerializer, connectionSettings) =>
    new JsonNetSerializer(builtInSerializer, connectionSettings, () => new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
    }));

var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
```